# Benefits of MS Business Intelligence tools

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm wondering are `MS BI tools` are really useful? I've already used `SSRS` - and it is quite useful.

1. But what about `SSIS`? Is it tool for just `Extract, Transform and Load` from some other file extensions (for example txt, xls) to database? But for this reasons (I'm not sure) should be some other simpler tools. Is it reasonble to build complicated flows in `SSIS`.
2. I've read some sources, and everywhere I saw "build `data warehouses`". But data warehouse is just another database. Couldn't we just create query that copies data from one database to another (data warehouse) and assign a job, which by schedule will update that database. Why to use `SSIS` here?
3. In my workplace, most reports are built date to date, that is, if somebody loaded some data to database, someone may need to build report immediately. How `SSIS` could be useful here? In my opinion, it is not reasonable to enter data both to main database and to `Data Warahouse.` Is it still advisable to use Data Warehouse in this case and why and how can I accomplish this without using much resources?

It would be quite helpful if you explain above points by simple examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, there could be more easier solutions but SSIS provides comprehensive bunch of components ready out of the box. Especially when you are dealing with MS stack mostly. They just work right after drag & drop + few params configured
2. To build a data warehouse is a one of bold targets of any modern ETL platform. It's just a sort of mind set that ETL presence means somewhere around someone is building sort of data warehouse.
   But there are dozens other less complex tasks to automate with SSIS as ETL platform.
3. At least you may want to automate this data loading to DB by bringing SSIS in place. Afterwards reports extraction based on just loaded data could also be automated. You don't need to follow any of data warehouse patter or technique - you just operate with Data Source / Destination and set of intermediary transformations if any.

Also what could be underlined - if something is missing from SSIS palette of components that could be developed using any of .NET languages.
You may take a look at following resource http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/ to understand how flexible it could be.